# angularjs adding selected items from dropdowns to the scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a table which has a dropdown above each column where the number of columns is dynamic. I created this as follows

```
            <table class='table' >
                <tr>
                    <th ng-repeat= "item in importTable[0]">
                        <select ng-model="selectedItem" ng-options="i.Name for i in optionList"></select>
                    </th>
                </tr>
                <tr ng-repeat="row in importTable">
                    <td ng-repeat="item in row">{{ item }} </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
```

Where optionList is the list of options in the dropdowns. All of the dropdowns have the same optionList.

How do I add the selected item along with the index of the column it is above to the scope to the model?

Here is a link to JSfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/769/ just click import. I want to be able to define which column is which type.

Comment: The column index should then be a property of each item in the array. Post what you are actually trying to do in a fiddle or something. It seems like you are looking for a solution to a solution to a problem that we don't know about.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply here is a link. i hope this explains it better! http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/769/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use $index variable that is provided by [ngRepeat](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angRepeat) to set the ngModel to a specific item in an array:

In your controller you first define the array that will hold all the models:

```
function ImportCtrl($scope) {   
  $scope.selectedItems = [];
  ...
}
```

And than, inside the ngRepeat you refer your ngModel to a specific item inside the `selectedItems`array:

```
<select ng-model="selectedItems[$index]" ng-options="i.Name for i in columnNames"></select>
```

[Demo FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/J2jha/)